# How can I calculate the minimum element-wise product of a right rotated array in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

Consider a one-dimensional array A of N integers. The element-place product of A is equal to Σ A [ k ] * k , i.e. it is the sum of the products formed when
multiply each element of the array by its position. Eg, the element-position product of the array¨

A = [5, 3, 2, 6, 4, 1]
is:
5 * 1 + 3 * 2 +2 * 3 + 6 * 4 + 4 * 5 + 1 * 6 = 67.

Rotating an array A by p positions (where 0 ≤ p < N) transforms A by taking its first p elements and putting them at the end. Eg, rotating A = [5, 3, 2, 6, 4, 1] by 2 places gives [2, 6, 4, 1, 5, 3].

I want to write a function in c++ that accepts A and N as parameters, and calculates the right rotation by p=1 of the array A with the minimum element-position product. The function should print the elements of array A after this rotation and return the corresponding product.

Example 1: (N = 6)
A = [5, 3, 2, 6, 4, 1]

min_elem_pos_prod(A, N)

Output:

Product :64
Array: 6 4 1 5 3 2

| iterations |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| p=0 :67 | 5 | 3 | 2 | 6 | 4 | 1 |
| p=1 :76 | 3 | 2 | 6 | 4 | 1 | 5 |
| p=2 :73 | 2 | 6 | 4 | 1 | 5 | 3 |
| p=3 :64 | 6 | 4 | 1 | 5 | 3 | 2 |
| p=4 :79 | 4 | 1 | 5 | 3 | 2 | 6 |
| p=5 :82 | 1 | 5 | 3 | 2 | 6 | 4 |

I have function that right rotates a array :

```
#include <iostream>

void rotateRight(int arr[], int size) {
    int p = 1 ;
    int end = size - 1 ;
   
    for (int i = 0; i < p; i++) {
        int temp = arr[end];
        for (int j = end; j > 0; j--) {
            arr[j] = arr[j - 1];
         }
       arr[0] = temp;
    }
}
```

and the element wise product :

```
int elementWiseProduct(int arr[], int N) {
    int sum = 0; 
   
    for (int i = 0,j=1; i < N; ++i,j++) {
        sum += arr[i]*j;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

my question is how can I combine those two or some other function to output the needed result  ?

Comment: How do you get this? `5 * 1 + 3 * 2 +2 * 3 + 6 * 4 + 4 * 5 + 1 * 6`. Left side of product is original array but the rotated array does not make sense to me. Please add details on how you got the second array.

Comment: `std::size_t bestP = 0; int bestScore = elementWiseProduct(A, N); for (int p = 1; p != N; ++p) { rotateRight(A, N); if (auto score = elementWiseProduct(A, N); score < bestScore) { bestScore = score; bestP= p; }}`?

Comment: `elementWiseProduct` is wrong BTW: `product += (i+1) * a[i];`

Comment: @Jarod42 yes I will edit it.Thank you for answer.Write it as an answer please in the post.

Comment: Note: Jerod's example is using an `if` with an initializer.  [That's a relatively new trick](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) you'll need at least C++17 for.

Comment: *"by taking its first p elements and putting them at the end."*, So it is `rotateLeft`, not `rotateRight`.

Comment: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/zPhMr4349) of my previous comment.

Comment: I don't understand.  Regardless of which direction the array is rotated, the elements are still the same.  So, why bother rotating?  The minimum value will be the minimum value regardless of its position.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Look at OP `elementWiseProduct`. rotating the array would change the computed value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so N-1 is the max amount of rotations you can do before getting our original array, so let us simply do this (and modify your rotateRight() method to accept p as parameter):

```
// Calculate product without any rotation
int product = elementWiseProduct(A, N);
int numberOfRotations = 0;

// Calculate product for all possible rotations
// Replace values initialized above if product is smaller
for (int i = 1; i <= N - 1; i++) {
    // Rotate once as your current implementation does
    rotateRight(A, N, 1);
    // Get the element-wise product of this rotation
    int newProduct = elementWiseProduct(A, N);
    if (newProduct < product) {
        product = newProduct;
        numberOfRotations = i;
    }
}
// Rotate array to get to the correct rotation
// Rotation needed is one more since we need to cycle 
// back to original array with one rotation
rotateRight(A, N, numberOfRotations + 1);

// Print array and minimum product
...
```